# missing-input-response | Invisible reCaptcha

Tags: php, html, post, recaptcha, invisible

So, I'm trying to implement to some website the brand new Invisible reCaptcha by Google.

I am following the steps exactly but it continously gives me missing-input-reponse error.

HTML Code:

```
<form id="subscribe-form" class="form-inline" action="phpScripts/subscribe/subscribeHandler.php" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address" required>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="g-recaptcha btn btn-danger" data-sitekey="6LfoNhkUAAAAAEcQFx8vGHZKHXsZ_q0j2KDnmU9M" data-callback="submitForm">Subscribe</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
include 'databaseConnection.php';
if($_POST){
            $secret = "MY SECRET KEY";
            $captcha= $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $url= file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha&remoteip=$ip");
            print_r($url);
            $decodedResponse = json_decode($url, TRUE);

            if($decodedResponse['success'] == 1){//code here}
```

So, I'm thinking that my $captcha variable cannot "catch" nothing from the POST of g-recaptcha-response. But why, this is exactly how Google says and exactly as the old reCaptcha v2.

Aswell, i have included `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem for several hours, until I finally understood the logic behind this "invisible-captcha" !
the reason you don't get a response is simply because there is an empty textarea element with an id and name of `g-recaptcha-response`
this textarea only populates with the response string **after** the challenge has been completed (which happens normally in the usual recaptcha), but for "invisible-captcha" you must explicitly call `grecaptcha.execute();` with your "submit" button, after which the textarea is populated, and your form is automatically submitted (assuming you have bound the submission with your `callback` function).
In my case, I already have php handling the form and recaptcha validation, so I decided to stick with the old "checkbox" version (at least until it gets improved), because I realized it will be really annoying to change everything (form submission logic, button action and JavaScript code) just to hide a checkbox! especially that both methods are nearly the same !

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be that you're tying the functionality to a button possibly.

Try implementing the code they give you when creating your keys:

```
<form id="subscribe-form" class="form-inline" action="phpScripts/subscribe/subscribeHandler.php" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address" required>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{keyhere}"></div>  
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-sitekey=" data-callback="submitForm">Subscribe</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

For the PHP logic validation:

```
if ( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) {
$secret = '{keyhere}';
$response = file_get_contents( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $secret . "&response=" . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );
        $response = json_decode( $response );
        if ( ! $response->success ) {
            //return error
        }

        //code logic below
}
```

The div code provided when creating the keys should properly generate all of the HTML from their end to be able to processed by your PHP validation when submitting your form.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

- Client Side

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>reCaptcha</title>

    <!--api link-->
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <!--call back function-->
    <script>
        function onSubmit(token) {
            document.getElementById('reCaptchaForm').submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form id="reCaptchaForm" action="signup.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="type anything">
        <!--Invisible reCaptcha configuration-->
        <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<your site key>" data-callback='onSubmit'>Submit</button>
        <br/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

- Server Side validation: Create a **signup.php** file

```html
<?php
//only run when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $secretKey = '<your secret key>';
    $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];     
    $remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


    $reCaptchaValidationUrl = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$response&remoteip=$remoteIp");
    $result = json_decode($reCaptchaValidationUrl, TRUE);

    //get response along side with all results
    print_r($result);

    if($result['success'] == 1) {
        //True - What happens when user is verified
        $userMessage = '<div>Success: you\'ve made it :)</div>';
    } else {
        //False - What happens when user is not verified
        $userMessage = '<div>Fail: please try again :(</div>';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>reCAPTCHA Response</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if(!empty($userMessage)) {
                echo $userMessage;
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use grecaptcha.reset() to reset the recaptcha after each execution and all should work just fine. Follow [this link](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#explicit_render) for more info on grecaptcha.reset().

Comment: Please write a few descriptions.